# Adding another class to visited links

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of links to posts like this, and I want to add visited class on those which are already visited.

```
<router-link
    v-for="post in posts"
    :key="post.id"
    active-class="active"
    class="link"
    tag="li"
    :to="{ name: 'post', params: { id: post.id } }" >
        <a>{{ post.icon }} {{post.title}}</a>
</router-link>
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these visited links?

Comment: Just to show them in different color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `:visited` Selector

> Select all visited links.

```
a:visited { 
    color: pink;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't work, plus I would like to save visited links in local storage

Comment: @Žilvinas It probably didn't work because you have a CSS selector more specific. Inspect the link in your browser. This answer is the correct one. Pay attention to the `:visited` selector, that's all that matters.

Comment: I fixed that, it was css issue. I somehow thought that this is incompatible with vue apps.

Actually :visited doesn't give too much styling capabilities but this is http://joelcalifa.com/blog/revisiting-visited/ exactly what I want to implement, anyways, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
a:visited { 
    //code here
}
```

:D

Comment: Add some of description here.